# ML model.fit() not working - `tf.data.Dataset` only supports Python-style

Tags: python, machine-learning, model

I'm trying to train a model in Jupyter Notebook, but I get an error:

```
--> 503   raise RuntimeError("`tf.data.Dataset` only supports Python-style "
    504                      "iteration in eager mode or within tf.function.")

RuntimeError: `tf.data.Dataset` only supports Python-style iteration in eager mode or within tf.function.
```

This is the part of the code:

```
model = create_model()
model.fit(
    x=train_images, 
    y=train_labels, 
    epochs=10,
    batch_size=256)
```

it does not work. I tried googling, but I couldn't find a sure solution.

Comment: Please add some code of how you created your dataset. Also, if you are using tf.data, you don't need to supply `y` in `fit`